# Formatting of multi-line Chapter heading with scrreprt: vertical alignment

Tags: formatting, chapters, scrreprt

I am not too much into Latex and after a long time of fruitless tinkering, I would like to ask a question here.

I am writing a large document, using the scrbook KOMA-script. For chapter heading formatting, I am using a style like this ([https://texblog.org/2012/07/03/fancy-latex-chapter-styles/][1]):

[image]

For single line headings, this looks fine.
However, for multi-line chapter headings I would like to change the style such that the grey bar extends to all lines and the chapter number is vertically aligned in the middle of the grey bar.

original:[image: original]
changed (changes marked in red for illustration only):[image: change]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \thechapter \enskip
  \textcolor{gray!50}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{2pt}{\baselineskip}}\enskip 
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Single-line Chapter}
\chapter{Multi-line Chapter Multi-line Chapter Multi-line Chapter Multi-line Chapter }
\end{document}
```

It would be great if someone could help me. Thanks a lot in advance!

Kind regards,
Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\chapterlinesformat`, eg.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily\mdseries\scshape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\thechapter}

\newsavebox\chapternumberbox
\newsavebox\chaptertextbox

\let\originalchapterlinesformat\chapterlinesformat
\renewcommand\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
  \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}
    {\ifstr{#1}{chapter}
      {%
        \savebox\chapternumberbox{#2}%
        \savebox\chaptertextbox{%
          \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-\wd\chapternumberbox-1em-2pt\relax}{\raggedright#3}%
        }%
        \raisebox{\dimexpr-.25\dp\strutbox}
          {\usebox\chapternumberbox}%
        \enskip
        \textcolor{gray!50}{%
          \rule[\dimexpr-\dp\chaptertextbox-.5ex\relax]{2pt}
            {\dimexpr\ht\chaptertextbox+\dp\chaptertextbox+1ex\relax}%
        }%
        \enskip
        \usebox\chaptertextbox
        \par
      }
      {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Single-line Chapter}
\chapter{Multi-line Chapter Multi-line Chapter Multi-line Chapter Multi-line Chapter }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That nails it, thanks so much, esdd!

Comment: How to change your code so that the chapter number is aligned with the first line of the title in case of a multiline chapter title? I tried several different values for the \raisebox command but could not make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul Use option `t` `\parbox[t]{...}{...}` for `\chaptertextbox` and do not raise `\chapternumberbox`. If you need more help, then ask a new question.